# Правильный ли код написан

Tags: python, python-3.x

вообщем есть задание учу python и подошел к оператору if [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код  правильно ли я все сделал?
код работает но мне кажется что можно было  намного проще

```py
age = int(input("Введите ваш возраст: "))
def users_age(age1):
    age1 = int(age)
    if age1 > 1:
        if age1 < 7:
            print("ты должен учиться в детском саду")
    if age1 > 7:
        if age1 < 18:
            print("ты должен учиться в школе")
    if age1 > 18:
        if age1 < 30:
            print("ты должен учиться в вузе")
    if age1 > 30:
        if age1 < 60:
            print("ты должен работать")
        else:
            print("ты Пенсионер Или еще не родился")
    return age1
users_age(print(f"тебе {age}"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что Вы неправильно выполнили задание.

Больше всего ошибок у Вас в пункте 3:

- *"Вызвать функцию, передав ей возраст пользователя..."*

Так звучит задание. Вы же почему-то передаёте результат работы функции `print`, то есть `None`.
А в самой функции Вы упорно не обращаете никакого внимания на аргумент, сразу же обращаясь к глобальной переменной.

Это плохая практика, Вам следовало бы сделать так:

```py
age = int(input('Введите ваш возраст: '))
users_age(age)
```

К тому же, обработка аргументов должна происходить, желательно, вне самой функции, то есть функция должна ожидать только число (`int`).

- *"Положить результат работы функции в переменную."*

Вы вовсе этого не сделали.

Должно быть так:

```py
result = users_age(age)
```

- *"Вывести содержимое переменной на экран"*

```py
print(result)
```

---

Теперь стоит поговорить о самой функции:

- У Вас ошибка в самом алгоритме — Вы не учитываете крайние случаи. Попробуйте ввести `7` и Вы всё поймёте.
- Ваша функция не чистая. Это термин из функционального программирования. Ваша функция явно обращается к внешней среде через `print`, этого можно и нужно избежать.
- Код не *"Pythonic-style"*, Вы не используете довольно удобные конструкции языка, поэтому Ваш код довольно громоздкий.

Первый пункт легко исправляется использованием операторов `<=` и `>=`.
Второй — использованием инструкции `return`.
Третий — использованием конструкции `if-elif` и расширенным сравнением (`x < y < z`).

---

***Пример:***

```py
def users_age(age):
    if 1 <= age < 7:
        return "ты должен учиться в детском саду"
    elif 7 <= age < 18:
        return "ты должен учиться в школе"
    elif 18 <= age < 30:
        return "ты должен учиться в вузе"
    elif 30 <= age < 60:
        return "ты должен работать"
    return "ты Пенсионер Или еще не родился"


def main():
    age = int(input('Введите ваш возраст: '))

    result = users_age(age)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Также я использовал конструкцию `if __name__ == '__main__':`, что позволяет повторно использовать функционал, импортируя функции, без побочного эффекта в виде исполнения при импорте.

Comment: Стоило бы написать и про аннотации типа, раз уж вы их использовали в коде. Или убрать, чтобы не путать новичка.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за замечание, пожалуй уберу. Это довольно обширная тема, не думаю, что смогу уместить в пояснение.

Comment: @nomnoms12 в данном случае расширенное сравнение избыточно, так как используется elif. Согласны?

Comment: @Ghostik2005 Я думал об этом. Тогда придётся сначала проверять крайние случаи, то есть первое условие будет выглядеть так: `if age < 1 or age >= 60`. Мне не нравится такой стиль, поэтому я предпочёл расширенное сравнение, оно более очевидно на мой взгляд.

Comment: @nomnoms12 если не нравиться такой стиль, то зачем в каждом elif делать граничные условия? И к тому же это путаница для новичка, он тогда не поймет разницу работы if от if-elif

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(input("Введите ваш возраст: "))

def users_age(age):
    result = "ты Пенсионер Или еще не родился"
    if age > 1 and age < 7:
        result = "ты должен учиться в детском саду"
    elif age < 18:
        result = "ты должен учиться в школе"
    elif age < 30:
        result = "ты должен учиться в вузе"
    elif age < 60:
        result = "ты должен работать"
    return result

result = users_age(age)
print(result)
```

Если быстро на коленке.